# How does the VAR decide which camera to use?

Tags: rules, football, officiating, video-review

On April 17, 2019, in the UEFA Champions League quarterfinal second leg between Manchester City and Tottenham there were some requests to VAR.

In particular, one was made regarding Llorente's goal in 73', Tottenham's third goal and making the score 4-3, which would (and did) qualify his team to the semifinals.

Cameras show Llorente touching the ball with his arm, but it was attached to his body. Depending on the camera angle, it may look intentional.

In the The Guardian article, [Pep Guardiola hits out at VAR after Llorente’s disputed goal for Spurs](https://www.theguardian.com/football/2019/apr/17/pep-guardiola-var-lorente-champions-league-spurs-manchester-city),

> "I support VAR but maybe from one angle Fernando Llorente’s goal is handball, maybe from the referee’s angle it is not,” Guardiola said.

Is there a rule on what angle should be used to take the decision? Do teams have the right to ask for a new check with other cameras?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Law 5.4](http://theifab.com/laws/the-referee-2018/chapters/video-assistant-referee-var-2018) states that the VAR uses *replay(s)*, so there is no limitation in what sort of replays are being used. Usually all with a proper perspective on the scene.

> The assistance from the video assistant referee (VAR) will relate to
>   using replay(s) of the incident.

When you watch the live footage of the VAR or referee in the review area you can clearly see that they watch the scene from different angles, so Pep Guardiola's comment was nonsense. Also the VAR can only overturn a decision when it was an obvious error:

> The referee may be assisted by a video assistant referee (VAR) only in
>   the event of a ‘clear and obvious error’ or ‘serious missed incident’
>   in relation to:
>
> - goal/no goal
> - penalty/no penalty
> - direct red card (not second caution)
> - mistaken identity when the referee cautions or sends off the wrong player of the offending team

And my personal two cents: The goal was good. The ball went in from his upper leg and *maybe* barely touched the arm with no visual evidence.

Comment: Also helpful as evidence, the first 80 seconds of [FIFA's video explaining VAR for the 2018 World Cup](https://youtu.be/YdwOL08NfxQ) is clear that multiple angles are used by VAR and provided to the match referee.

Comment: However, I think Guardiola's comment is not that VAR got the decision wrong, but just that the same incident can appear to be either of two things depending on angle - this is absolutely true when looking at e.g. are shots on target, did balls cross lines, or were tackles legitimate.